# Make box shadow and bring text closer to text

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

How can make shadow to every block of text, when I do it I lose my animation and it doesn`t work correctly. That`s why I did it to 2 blocks, but I need 4 blocks with shadow. So, how can I do that, and how can I bring 4 block of texts more closely to image?
I have this css:

```
.div-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

 :root {
  --time: 24;
}

.div-txt p.label {
  color: #0065de;
  font: bold 16px 'Arial';
  animation-duration: calc(var(--time) * 1s);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: color-change;
}

.div-txt:nth-child(1) p.label:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.div-txt:nth-child(1) p.label:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 4 * 1s);
}

.div-txt:nth-child(3) p.label:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 2 * 1s);
}

.div-txt:nth-child(3) p.label:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.33 * 1s);
}

.div-img {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 100%;
  /*  border: 2px solid #ccc;*/
  /*  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(153,153,153,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);*/
}

.div-img img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  animation-duration: calc(var(--time) * 1s);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: fade;
}

.div-img img:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.div-img img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 8 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 4 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 2.66 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 2 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.6 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.33 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.14 * 1s);
}

@keyframes color-change {
  0%,
  25%,
  100% {
    color: #0065de;
  }
  1%,
  24% {
    color: #ED0008;
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  0%,
  20%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: auto;
  }
  1%,
  99% {
    z-index: 1;
  }
  8%,
  12% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1170px) {
    .div-wrap {
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}
```

and this html:

```
 <div class="div-wrap">
  <div class="div-txt" style="box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);">

    <img src="img/svgforlia/connect.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
    <p class="label" style="margin-top: 5px;">Connect</p>
    <p>Wear Lia device on the shoulders, <br>turn on it and connect application <br>with device.</p>

    <img src="img/svgforlia/calibrate.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
    <p class="label" style="margin-top: 5px;">Calibrate</p>
    <p>After connection, set up calibration to <br>help device remember your upright <br>and slouch positions.</p>

  </div>
  <div class="div-img">
    <img src="img/mockups/2.png" title="Image 1">
    <img src="img/mockups/3.png" title="Image 2">
    <img src="img/mockups/5.png" title="Image 3">
    <img src="img/mockups/6.png" title="Image 4">
    <img src="img/mockups/7.png" title="Image 5">
    <img src="img/mockups/8.png" title="Image 6">
    <img src="img/mockups/9.png" title="Image 7">
    <img src="img/mockups/10.png" title="Image 8">
  </div>
  <div class="div-txt" style="box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);">

    <img src="img/svgforlia/train.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
    <p class="label" style="color: #0065de;">Train</p>
    <p>Train your posture anytime you want, <br>set up daily goal to improve gradually <br>your posture.</p>

    <img src="img/svgforlia/analyze.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
    <p class="label" style="margin-top: 5px;">Analyze</p>
    <p>Statistics let you track and analyze the <br>progress you’ve made from first <br>training to the last.</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

How I can do it without losing responsive design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'white-space' on the right is because of the `div-img` element which has a fixed width of 600px; So of course when the screen is smaller than `600px` , that element will cause a horizontal scroll.

You should use media queries to make the div 100% width when below 600px;

About the second issue with the `box-shadow` i made `div-txt` class wrap around each img and text. So now you have 4 `div-txt` instead of 2.

Also added a width to the divs of 70%. You can edit that how you want.

The css added is :

```
.div-txt {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The box shadow is the one you wrote it as inline style to the div.

see below or [jsFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3warzypn/1/)

```css
.div-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

:root {
  --time: 24;
}

.div-txt p.label {
  color: #0065de;
  font: bold 16px 'Arial';
  animation-duration: calc(var(--time) * 1s);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: color-change;
}

.div-txt:nth-child(1) p.label {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.div-txt:nth-child(2) p.label {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 4 * 1s);
}

.div-txt:nth-child(4) p.label {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 2 * 1s);
}

.div-txt:nth-child(5) p.label {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.33 * 1s);
}

.div-img {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  /*  border: 2px solid #ccc;*/
  /*  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(153,153,153,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);*/
}

.div-img img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  animation-duration: calc(var(--time) * 1s);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: fade;
}

.div-img img:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.div-img img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 8 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 4 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 2.66 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 2 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.6 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.33 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.14 * 1s);
}

.div-txt {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@keyframes color-change {
  0%,
  25%,
  100% {
    color: black;
  }
  1%,
  24% {
    color: #ED5F8A;
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  0%,
  20%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: auto;
  }
  1%,
  99% {
    z-index: 1;
  }
  8%,
  12% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .div-wrap {
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  .div-img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-wrap">
  <div class="div-txt">

    <img src="img/svgforlia/connect.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
    <p class="label" style="margin-top: 5px;">Connect</p>
    <p>Wear Lia device on the shoulders, <br>turn on it and connect application <br>with device.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div-txt">
    <img src="img/svgforlia/calibrate.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
    <p class="label" style="margin-top: 5px;">Calibrate</p>
    <p>After connection, set up calibration to <br>help device remember your upright <br>and slouch positions.</p>
  </div>



  <div class="div-img">
    <img src="img/mockups/2.png" title="Image 1">
    <img src="img/mockups/3.png" title="Image 2">
    <img src="img/mockups/5.png" title="Image 3">
    <img src="img/mockups/6.png" title="Image 4">
    <img src="img/mockups/7.png" title="Image 5">
    <img src="img/mockups/8.png" title="Image 6">
    <img src="img/mockups/9.png" title="Image 7">
    <img src="img/mockups/10.png" title="Image 8">
  </div>
  <div class="div-txt" style="">

    <img src="img/svgforlia/train.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
    <p class="label" style="color: #0065de;">Train</p>
    <p>Train your posture anytime you want, <br>set up daily goal to improve gradually <br>your posture.</p>



  </div>
  <div class="div-txt">
    <img src="img/svgforlia/analyze.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
    <p class="label" style="margin-top: 5px;">Analyze</p>
    <p>Statistics let you track and analyze the <br>progress you’ve made from first <br>training to the last.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: does it work in the jsfiddle i provided ? https://jsfiddle.net/3warzypn/

Comment: no ? i am watching now the jsfiddle and there is no more white space like it was before. the whitespace is gone

Comment: if this solves your original question. Please rate and accept the answer. If you have another question just post a separate question. Otherwise it will be confusing for anyone that has the same problem and reads this question. I will do my best to answer your second question. Just post it separately.

Comment: ok then. edit your question with the new requirements. Explain in detail what you want to achieve

Comment: i can't see any shadow in your css. do you mean `box-shadow ` ?

Comment: i made 4 box shadows. not 2. i made 4 `div-txt`  instead of 2. Please check again -> https://jsfiddle.net/3warzypn/1/

Comment: the titles change their colors. from purple to black. what do you mean `animation doesnt work correctly`  ?

Comment: changed the css for animation-delay on `p.label` . check now if this is what you wanted ?

Comment: that's pretty simple. try doing that yourself. or try a freelancing site

Answer (score 0):

adding `overflow: hidden` to div-wrap do the job. Which is a workaround.

You can also fix `<div class="div-img">` which have 600px width on mobile and expanding parent container. Adding `max-width:100%` to it fix the issue.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L9sm5ua1/

Comment: Blaszynski, I still see big space

Comment: Are you sure? I have checked my fiddle in chrome on mobile resolutions and there is no blank space

Comment: Blaszynski, YES! it works! Thank you very much. So can you help in one more question. How can I make the box-shadow for every of 4 texts? look at my question I changed it. And how can I bring text to the image?

Answer (score 0):

U specified width: 600px; and thats why the page shows 600px while its not in mobile view. .

Do some media queries for small devices or delete the width:600px from below

```
.div-img {
        position: relative;
        height: 600px;
        /*  width: 600px; 
        /*  border: 2px solid #ccc;*/
        /*  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(153,153,153,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);*/
    }
```